# Merge specific array values into single value

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I have parsed a csv file which gives me an array like this:

```
[{
"year": 2019,
"month": 6,
"day": 25,
"hour": 4,
"minute": 0,
"temperature": 26.52
},
{
"year": 2019,
"month": 6,
"day": 25,
"hour": 4,
"minute": 0,
"temperature": 26.52
}]
```

I want to merge `minute`,`hour`,`day`,`month`,`year` to a single key. Like this:

```
"time": "2019-07-02 09:57:35"
```

so i can use this as a datetime object on my API.

The way I am currently getting data is:

```
 const cleanKeys = [
         'year',
         'month',
         'day',
         'hour',
         'minute',
         'temperature',

     ];

    const dataAsObject = totalData.map(function (values) {
        return cleanKeys.reduce(function (o, k, i) {
            o[k] = values[i];
            return o;
        }, {})
    });
```

This is basically adding a header key to all data. I am only interested in merging `minute`, `hour`, `day`, `month`, `year` column.

Comment: OK...what's stopping you from just doing `year + "-" + month`, etc?

Comment: That wouldn't be an array - we call them objects in JavaScript

Comment: Is there any way I can do this inside of loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use built in [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```js
var obj = {"year": 2019,
"month": 6,
"day": 25,
"hour": 4,
"minute": 0,
"temperature": 26.52};

const date = new Date(obj.year, obj.month - 1, obj.day, obj.hour, obj.minute);

const newObj = {date, temperature: obj.temperature};

console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj));
```

EDIT:

please find below updated answer using date in loop:

```js
const arr = [{
"year": 2019,
"month": 6,
"day": 25,
"hour": 4,
"minute": 0,
"temperature": 26.52
},
{
"year": 2019,
"month": 6,
"day": 25,
"hour": 4,
"minute": 0,
"temperature": 26.52
}];

const newArr = arr.reduce((a,c) => {
 const date = new Date(c.year, c.month - 1, c.day, c.hour, c.minute);
 a.push({date, temperature: c.temperature});
 return a;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr));
```

Comment: How can I do this inside of loop? If you look closely to how I am getting the data you may understand

Answer (score 0):

You can create the string yourself, e.g.:

```
yourArray["time"] = `${yourArray.year}-${yourArray.month}-${yourArray.day} ${yourArray.hours}:${yourArray.minutes}:${yourArray.seconds}`;
```

Comment: Nice, but can I use this on reduce method?